# Import "izip" for different versions of Python

Tags: python, dynamic-loading

A common idiom that I use for Python2-Python3 compatibility is:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  #python3.x
    izip = zip
```

However, a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598244/zip-and-groupby-curiosity-in-python-2-7/16598378?noredirect=1#comment23859060_16598378) on one of my Stack Overflow answers implies that there may be a better way.  Is there a more clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Perhaps the commenter meant to use the import to shadow `zip`? I.e., `try: from itertools import izip as zip; except ImportError: pass`. (Please excuse the lack of newlines.)

Comment: Perhaps -- (I knew about that one).  I was just wondering if there was some magic with `__import__` that I didn't know about or something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure this is really an answer, or I should elaborate on my comment, and in hindsight probably not even a very good comment anyway, but:

Firstly, you can just simplify it to:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip as zip
except ImportError: # will be 3.x series
    pass
```

What I was thinking about was:

From 2.6 you can use [as per the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html):

```
from future_builtins import map # or zip or filter
```

You do however then have the same problem of `ImportError` - so:

```
try:
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError: # not 2.6+ or is 3.x
    try:
        from itertools import izip as zip # < 2.5 or 3.x
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

The advantage of using `future_builtin` is that it's in effect a bit more "explicit" as to intended behaviour of the module, supported by the language syntax, and possibly recognised by tools. <strike>For instance, I'm not 100% sure, but believe that the 2to3 tool will re-write `zip` correctly as `list(zip(...` in this case, while a plain `zip = izip` may not be... But that's something that needs looking in to.</strike>

Updated - also in the docs:

> The 2to3 tool that ports Python 2 code to Python 3 will recognize this usage and leave the new builtins alone.

Comment: Ahh ... I didn't actually know about `future_builtins`.  It seems a little silly that they don't have that in python3 though.  I don't know why they didn't do something like `from __future__ import zip` instead.  That would have made sense to me.  Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I also think it's silly that 2to3 recognizes the usage of `future_builtins` yet leaves the `from future_builtins import whatever` statement(s) in the output.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to make Python 2.x code compatible with Python 3.x you should look at six:

http://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves

Comment: Yeah, `six` is nice.  Generally, if it's simple enough though, I tend to prefer to avoid the extra dependency.

Answer (score 3):

This is roughly twice as fast as using a try/except:

```
import itertools
zip = getattr(itertools, 'izip', zip)
```

Comment: I find this claim hard to believe ... [`getattr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96c7c0685045b739fdc5145018cddfd252155713/Python/bltinmodule.c#L993) works by catching the `AttributeError` and substituting the default value.  Admittedly, that's implemented in C so it might be slightly faster, but I find it hard to believe that there's a factor of 2.  I also find it hard to believe that the time would matter in the real world if you have this at the top-level of your module... Finally, this _is_ possibly the cleanest way to write it that I've seen.  Kudos for that :-).

Comment: @mgilson: Use `timeit` and test it yourself.  I thought it might be faster, but I didn't think ~2x.